# iphone screen dimensions: safari live debugging vs chrome dev tools

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, responsive-design

Just wondering...

Why are the screen dimensions for an iphone in Chrome dev tools, well as on multiple other sites discussing responsive webdesign, about 320x480.

However, when I go into safari's live web development webinspector and plug my iphone and do: window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, I get 189 width & 220 height.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty interesting articles on pixels: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html
http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis